# How to get the original value of a copied cell in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, copy-paste

How to get the underlying value when a cell is copied in kendo grid ?

I've the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#cellSelection").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: orders,
                            pageSize: 6
                        },
                        selectable: "multiple cell",
                        allowCopy: true,
                        pageable: {
                            buttonCount: 5
                        },
                        scrollable: false,
                        navigatable: true,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "ShipCountry",
                                title: "Ship Country",
                                width: 300
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Freight",
                                width: 300
                            },
                            {
                                field: "OrderDate",
                                title: "Order Date",
                                format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
                            }
                        ]
                    });

                    //events to capture when Ctrl + C is pressed
                    $("#cellSelection").bind('copy', function (e) {
                        var grid = $("#cellSelection").data("kendoGrid");
                        if (grid != null && grid.areaClipBoard != undefined) {
                            console.log("copied content is:");
                            console.log(grid.areaClipBoard.val());
                        }
                    });
                });
```

So, when you copy a cell, the value which is visible in the cell is being copied.

Say, if the value you are copying from grid is `40.65` then only that value is copied with `allowCopy` set to true in kendo grid. But the original value as per the data source is `40.6789`. I need the original value to be copied to clipboard when <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd> is pressed.

I wrote the copy event as you can see, it just outputs what is copied from the grid. Is there a way I can get the underlying value when <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd> is pressed ?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svat3Len/) link. Run the fiddle and open developer tools and select few cells and copy it. You should be able to see what is copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Cobus Kruger for your solution. Here is my complete solution.

1. We've to loop over the selected items in the grid and get the underlying data source values and return the result.

> ```
> function getTSVFormat(grid) {
>     var selected = grid.select();
>     var delimeter = '\t';
>     var allowCopy = grid.options.allowCopy;
>     var onlyVisible = true;
>     if ($.isPlainObject(allowCopy) && allowCopy.delimeter) {
>         delimeter = allowCopy.delimeter;
>     }
>     var text = '';
>     if (selected.length) {
>         if (selected.eq(0).is('tr')) {
>             selected = selected.find('td:not(.k-group-cell)');
>         }
>         if (onlyVisible) {
>             selected.filter(':visible');
>         }
>         var result = [];
>         var cellsOffset = grid.columns.length;
>         var lockedCols = grid._isLocked() && lockedColumns(grid.columns).length;
>         var inLockedArea = true;
>         $.each(selected, function (idx, cell) {
>             cell = $(cell);
>             var tr = cell.closest('tr');
>             var rowIndex = tr.index();
>             var cellIndex = cell.index();
>             if (onlyVisible) {
>                 cellIndex -= cell.prevAll(':hidden').length;
>             }
>             if (lockedCols && inLockedArea) {
>                 inLockedArea = $.contains(grid.lockedTable[0], cell[0]);
>             }
>             if (grid._groups() && inLockedArea) {
>                 cellIndex -= grid._groups();
>             }
>             cellIndex = inLockedArea ? cellIndex : cellIndex + lockedCols;
>             if (cellsOffset > cellIndex) {
>                 cellsOffset = cellIndex;
>             }
>             var cellText = cell.text();
>
>             var column = grid.columns[cellIndex];
>             var data = grid.dataItem(tr);
>             var cellData = data[column.field];
>
>             if (!result[rowIndex]) {
>                 result[rowIndex] = [];
>             }
>             result[rowIndex][cellIndex] = cellData;
>
>         });
>         var rowsOffset = result.length;
>         result = $.each(result, function (idx, val) {
>             if (val) {
>                 result[idx] = val.slice(cellsOffset);
>                 if (rowsOffset > idx) {
>                     rowsOffset = idx;
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>         $.each(result.slice(rowsOffset), function (idx, val) {
>             if (val) {
>                 text += val.join(delimeter) + '\r\n';
>             } else {
>                 text += '\r\n';
>             }
>         });
>     }
>     return text;
> }
> ```

Note that I didn't write the above function on my own. I've looked into kendo.all.js file and debugged it and customized for my own purpose.

2. After you get the copied text we've to call this in the copy event

> ```
> $("#cellSelection").bind('copy', function (e) {
>                     var grid = $("#cellSelection").data("kendoGrid");
>                     var text = getTSVFormat(grid);
>
>                     //add textarea if its not in yet
>                     if (!grid.areaClipBoard) {
>                         grid.areaClipBoard = $('<textarea />').css({
>                             position: 'fixed',
>                             top: '50%',
>                             left: '50%',
>                             opacity: 0,
>                             width: 0,
>                             height: 0
>                         }).appendTo(grid.wrapper);
>                     }
>
>                     //overwrite the default clipboard content of kendo with our custom data source
>                     grid.areaClipBoard.val(text);
>                     //call copy to clipboard to copy the contents
>                     copyToClipboard(text);
>                 });
> ```

3. As you can see in the copy event we'll have to overwrite the contents of areaClipBoard property to have our customized text.
4. After you copy the contents over to areaClipBoard, call copyToClipBoard with the html that you want to copy to clipboard.

> ```
> function copyToClipboard(html) {
>                 var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
>                 $(textarea).addClass('k-spreadsheet-clipboard').val(html).appendTo(document.body).focus().select();
>                 document.execCommand('copy');
>                 $(textarea).remove();
>             }
> ```

That's all ! You can now paste to any excel sheet as you wish to. It will have the exact same spaces for what you've selected in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

To get the data for the selected row, use:

```
grid.dataItem(grid.select());
```

In your case, you're using cell selection, and `grid.dataItem` returns `null`.

This forces you into the scenic route. To get the value, you need to:

1. Find the selected row from the selected cell.
2. Get the data for that row.
3. Determine the selected column.
4. Use the column to get to the field name.
5. From the row data and the field name, you can finally find the original value.

So to put this all together:

```
$("#cellSelection").bind('copy', function(e) {
  var grid = $("#cellSelection").data("kendoGrid");
  if (!grid) {
    return;
  }
  if (grid.areaClipBoard) {
    console.log("copied content is:", grid.areaClipBoard.val());
  }
  var cell = grid.select()[0];
  var row = cell.parentNode;
  var column = grid.columns[cell.cellIndex];
  var data = grid.dataItem(row);
  var cellData = data[column.field];
  console.log(cellData);    
});
```

A couple of notes about this:

1. I don't think my error handling is production-ready.
2. I'm only doing this for the first selected cell. You actually use `multiple cell`, and so you should probably iterate the results of `grid.select` and do this for each, concatenating by tabs or something. I don't know. You're the one who wanted multiple cells and copying.
3. If you may conceivably hide columns, then I don't think my way to get the column will work. I actually don't know what you should do then.

Comment: If I've to loop through the selected items and map the values with the datasource, then I've to push this again to clipboard in some specific format so that it should be able to paste as-is selected in grid to excel sheet

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. You didn't specify in the question what you wanted to do with multiple cells, so I had to guess :)

Comment: The default implementation of copy in kendo does provide the exact thing but it just copies whatever is displayed on the grid. I'm interested if we can tweak the default implementation of copy and push the original value instead of what is displayed on the grid

Comment: What I showed here is how to get back to the data that was used to populate the grid. It should not be affected by the formatting, truncation and other things that can happen in the grid. Are you asking about that, or about changing what copy does?

Comment: +1 thanks for your solution @Cobus. I've modified my solution to fit what I need. Will post it in a second

Answer (score 0):

if you need to show the Value with `40.6789` instead of `40.68`
I perform the formate in below Example... May be Help You

https://jsfiddle.net/svat3Len/4/

Comment: values have to be displayed with 2 precision but when copied it should retain the original value